# WebSockets or (Long poling and Posix's Multithread)

Tags: javascript, php, multithreading, websocket, comparison

I have learned `long polling` with `javascript` and mastered it, Now I am about to write `multithread` extension for php to build a chat site but one fellow programmer recommended `websockets` over `multithread` and `long polling`, so I got confused... I know that **Facebook** uses `long polling which returns JSON` string from server but I am unclear about how they handles server side considering websockets is new to world, they should have extended php to support multithread just like them, I need to build a professional chat site and avoid using node, jquery, etc.
 anyways my question is. 

**which one is more recommended for a busy chat site,  Websockets or posix's Multithread for server side ?**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Web Browser for chatting site, I would recommend using WebSocket. WebSocket is all event-driven so that there is no polling in the code side. Eventually these event handlers use polling (short or long) in the system level. You don't have to add another polling over the system-level polling.